# Returning outlook sender address from VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code I have copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894485/utilizing-outlook-events-from-excel/35899410#35899410) here. It triggers the myItems_ItemAdd when a new email is received and is run from within excel. (Note I am not able to call New Mail events directly from outlook)

```
 Private WithEvents myItems As Outlook.Items

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Dim oNS As Namespace
 Dim myOL As Outlook.Application
 Set myOL = New Outlook.Application
 Set oNS = myOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myItems = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

 End Sub

Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Debug.Print "Got_EMAIL!!!"
End Sub
```

I then wanted to access various other properties of the email like the subject. This for example works:

```
Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Debug.Print "Got_EMAIL!!!"
  Debug.Print Item.Subject     
End Sub
```

I would have thought as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender) that a MailItem (which Item is?) should be accessible with :

```
Debug.Print Item.Sender
```

But that results in a Run-time error '287'

[image]

I also tried lines:

```
 Debug.Print Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102")
 Debug.Print Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E")
 Debug.Print Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
```

Which has the error:

[image]

When I inspect the Item object I notice that Sender and MAPIObject are both empty. I have been unable to find an answer to why Sender properties would be accessed through Property Accessor.

How can I access the sender's email address?

*** UPDATE **

Item.Sender.Address results in Run-time error '287'
[image]

And as previously stated Sender and MAPIObject are both empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`.Sender` will return an `AddressEntry` object (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender)) that cannot be handled by `Debug.Print`. To get the email address as a string use `.Sender.Address`.

Note: the above gives the expected result when the sender is outside my organization, but not for my colleagues! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361726/how-can-i-get-the-sender-email-address-using-outlook-mailitem-in-vb-net) for a possible solution.

Comment: Perhaps this is a security issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776954/sender-senderemailaddress-missing-in-folder-items - I wonder if I can get sender from the headers.